# Spring cloud streams: Supplier method not found issue with later version of spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Streams with com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs:2.8.0, and I am using Supplier.

It works with Spring boot 2.3.12.RELEASE.

However, if I go to spring boot version >= 2.4.0, then I get the following error:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration.integrationFlowFromProvidedSupplier(FunctionConfiguration.java:252)

The following method did not exist:
org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows.from(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Lorg/springframework/integration/dsl/IntegrationFlowBuilder;

The method's class, org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/5.4.10/spring-integration-core-5.4.10.jar!/org/springframework/integration/dsl/IntegrationFlows.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows: file:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/5.4.10/spring-integration-core-5.4.10.jar

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows
```

Any ideas how to get working with later versions of spring boot?

As mentioned below, for current latest spring boot 2.4.5, required version 2020.0.3 for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies

Thanks,
B

Comment: You probably have mismatched versions; when going to a newer Boot version you need to go to a newer spring cloud version. See the table on the Spring Cloud page for compatible versions. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: Thanks gary, for spring cloud dependencies page.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit confusing but 2.3.12.RELEASE released after 2.4.0

Release dates

1. Version 2.3.12.RELEASE - released on **Jun, 2021**
2. Version 2.4.0 - released on **Nov, 2020**

Dependency hierarchy:

```
Azure Spring Cloud Stream Event Hubs Binder » 2.8.0
|_ Azure Spring Cloud Starter Event Hubs » 2.8.0
|___ Azure Spring Integration Event Hubs » 2.8.0
|_____ Azure Spring Integration Core » 2.8.0
|_______ org.springframework.integration » spring-integration-core >> 5.5.2
```

Possible solution:

**Try to increase version to 2.4.2 or later**